# Can't get websvn working

Tags: svn, svn-server

I am trying to setup websvn but I get an error when I try to access the repository:

```
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svnrep/workspace/history'
svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: PROPFIND request on '/svnrep/workspace/history' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

I've installed a Debian 8 virtual machine svn.mydomain.com with a static IP address for the purpose. Subversion is working fine and I can access the repository via `file:///` on the same machine but not via http. I have the following setup:

```
root@svn:~# ls /data/svnrep
workspace

root@svn:~# ls /data/svnrep/workspace
README.txt  conf  db  format  hooks  locks

root@svn:~# svn ls file:///data/svnrep/workspace
JavaProjects/
history/
scripts/
websites/

root@svn:~# svn ls http://localhost/svnrep/workspace
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/workspace'

svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: PROPFIND request on '/workspace' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed

root@svn:~# cat /etc/websvn/svn_deb_conf.inc 
<?php
// please edit /etc/websvn/config.php 
// or use dpkg-reconfigure websvn
$config->parentPath("/data/svnrep");
$config->setEnscriptPath("/usr/bin");
$config->setSedPath("/bin");
$config->useEnscript();
?>

root@svn:~# cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf | grep -v "#" | grep -v "//"

<Location /svn>

  DAV svn

  SVNPath /data/svnrep/workspace


  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd


  Require valid-user

</Location>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your server's config, you should use this URL: `http://localhost/svn`